# Problema al correr los seeders laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy teniendo problema con un seeder al momento de correr, pasa que en mi modelo tengo asignado un boot para el `creating`

```php
protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->user = Auth::id();
        });
    }
```

pero al crear todo con el seeder me coloca todo los usuarios en `null` porque no encuentra un usuario autenticado, como prodia solucionar esto?

```php
public function run()
    {
        Voter::factory()
            ->count(100)
            ->create();
    }
```

> (voterFactory)

```php
public function definition()
    {

        $username = $this->faker->userName();

        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->firstName(),
            'lastname' => $this->faker->lastName(),
            'user_id' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1, 50)
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu modelo puedes asignar por defecto `Auth::id()` o, en el caso de que sea nulo, el valor que le hayas asignado en el método `create`:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->user_id = Auth::id() ?? $model->user_id;
    });
}
```

Comment: gracias!, si me sirvio.